# Database disappeared from PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm a relative newbie, so please bear with me...  I created a typical wordpress database in PhPMyAdmin via MAMP (on Mac OSX 10.8).  I built up the site a bit, and yesterday evening I pulled up PhPMyAdmin and the database had completely disappeared.  Now there's just "information_schema", "mysql", "performance_schema", and an older wordpress database.

Though different users were created in PhPMyAdmin, I don't think this is a privledges issue b/c I'm logged in as root.

How, if possible, might I recover the database?  More importantly, can anyone give me insight into why the one database would completely disappear without a trace?

Let me know if I can further clarify.  Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin provides an easy way to switch between servers via a drop-down/select box. It is easy to connect to the wrong server, especially if you have more than one configured. Have you found that drop-down and verified that you are connected to the server that hosts your Wordpress database?

Comment: Try logging in from the command line client with `mysql -u root -p` and then typing `SHOW DATABASES;` to see if they all appear there. Normally this is an authentication issue as most installations come with an anonymous user that would have permission to see the three databases you describe. Double-check on the main phpMyAdmin page that you're logged in as root and also try to create a database to see whether you have those permissions.